# Check if JOIN exists and if column does not equal if it does

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
channel_titles
channel_grid
```

Inside `channel_grid`, there is a column named `col_id_15`.

I need to query for `entry_id` where

1. Either the `entry_id` **does not exist** in the `channel_grid` table
2. OR if the `entry_id` does exist in the `channel_grid` table, the `col_id_15` **is not equal** to `1`

I had thought that the following could work.

```
SELECT ct.entry_id
FROM channel_titles AS ct
LEFT JOIN channel_grid AS g ON g.entry_id = ct.entry_id                      
WHERE g.col_id_15 != '1'
```

Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Your query seems fine to me. Can you add the sample data in both tables and result data?

Comment: how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your two requirements, this should work:

```
SELECT ct.entry_id
FROM channel_titles AS ct
LEFT JOIN channel_grid AS g ON ct.entry_id = g.entry_id                      
WHERE g.entry_id IS NULL OR g.col_id_15 <> '1'
```

Just make sure that g.col_id_15 is a varchar, because the single quotes treat it as a string and not a number. If it's actually an INT, you can just take out the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems right. But if you want to get all entry_id which don't exist in the channel_grid table you must check g.entry_id is equal NULL.

```
SELECT ct.entry_id
FROM channel_titles AS ct
LEFT JOIN channel_grid AS g ON g.entry_id = ct.entry_id                      
WHERE g.entry_id IS NULL OR g.col_id_15 != '1'
```

That conditional is required because comparison any value with NULL always return NULL. For example:

```
SELECT NULL != '1' // return NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ct.entry_id
FROM channel_titles AS ct
LEFT JOIN channel_grid AS g ON g.entry_id = ct.entry_id                      
WHERE g.col_id_15 <> 1 OR g.entry_id IS NULL
```

Well, I think your question can be further simplified for easier understanding.